# Invalid Identifier While Joining Tables in JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to join 3 tables in JPA. When i am trying to associate CRL_IC_IMPORT_TRANS table i am getting error as Invalid Identifier as shown below

```
         from
            crl_ic investorco0_ 
        left outer join
            crl_ic_import_trans icimporttr1_ 
                on investorco0_.icimport_trans_event_id=icimporttr1_.event_id 
        left outer join
            crl_ic_order investorco2_ 
                on investorco0_.current_order_id=investorco2_.id
    "INVESTORCO0_"."ICIMPORT_TRANS_EVENT_ID": invalid identifier
```

Edit

```
from
    crl_ic investorco0_ 
left outer join
    crl_ic_order investorco1_ 
        on investorco0_.current_order_id=investorco1_.id
```

Error:

```
Provided id of the wrong type for class ICImportTrans. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String
```

Why its going to primary key in ICImportTrans class even after i mapped to a non PK ?

Below are my 3 tables and its keys. What is the mistake i am doing .

```
    @Table(name = "CRL_IC")
    public class ICLoanOrder {
          @Id
          @Column(name="EVENT_ID")
          String id;

          @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
          @JoinColumn(name = "EVENT_ID",referencedColumnName = "eventId" )
          ICImportTrans iCImportTrans;

          @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
          ICOrder currentOrder;  
     } 
         
     @Table(name = "CRL_IC_ORDER")
     public class ICOrder implements Serializable {

          @Id
          @GenericGenerator(name = "UUIDGenerator", strategy = "uuid2")
          @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUIDGenerator")
          @Type(type = "uuid-char")
          UUID id;

          @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
          @JsonIgnore
          @JoinColumn(name="EVENT_ID")
          ICLoanOrder iCLoanOrder;
          
     }
          
     @Table(name = "CRL_IC_IMPORT_TRANS")
     public class ICImportTrans implements Serializable {

          @Id
          @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ1")
          @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ1",sequenceName = "SEQ_IC_IMPORT",allocationSize = 1)
          @Column(name="PROCESS_ID")
          private Long processId;
          
          private String eventId;
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute SQL or JPQL ? And what are the query type here ? (the alias ending with _ make me think these are generated SQL by Hibernate, is it ?)

Answer (score 1):

The default name of the column should be `iCImportTrans_id`.
If you want to change it to `icimport_trans_event_id` you need to specify it in the `@JoinColumn`

```
    @Table(name = "CRL_IC")
    public class ICLoanOrder {
      ...
      
      @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      @JoinColumn(name = "icimport_trans_event_id", referencedColumnName = "eventId")
      ICImportTrans iCImportTrans;

      ...
    }
```

> Provided id of the wrong type for class ICImportTrans. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String

What kind of mapping are you trying to achieve?

In `ICLoanOrder` you mapped the id column and the association column to the same name `EVENT_ID`. I guess you want to use `ICImportTrans.eventId` as id of `ICLoanOrder`.

This willwork if you don't care about having an `id` field:

```
    @Entity(name="LoanOrder")
    @Table(name = "CRL_IC")
    public static class ICLoanOrder implements Serializable{
        @Id
        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "EVENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "eventId")
        ICImportTrans iCImportTrans;
    }
```

Normally, you would use `@MapsId`, but it seems to ignore the `referencedColumn` attribute and gives the same error.

Comment: Please See the new query formation after i changed the mapping . Why its trying to map to PK even after i mapped to a non PK field .

Comment: Unless his previous mapping with `@Id @Column(name="EVENT_ID") String id;` was nonsense, this would probably still fail due to type mismatch (Long/String). This is something to look out for as well

Comment: I've tested the mapping I've suggested so I'm pretty sure it was working but that's not how one usually maps  a `@OneToOne` using `@MapsId`. ANyway, it's not an unusual mapping

Comment: I actually think it's a bug. The correct mapping should be the one with @MapsId but when I test it I have the same error of the OP. I will have a better look later